# What is Custom Control and User Defined Control?

Tags: c#, user-controls, custom-controls

Can any explain me what is Custom Control and UserControl?The Main difference between them.Suggest me some basic examples links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What are user controls?**

User controls are custom, reusable controls, and they use the same techniques that are employed by HTML and Web server controls. They offer an easy way to partition and reuse common user interfaces across ASP.NET Web applications. They use the same Web Forms programming model on which a Web Forms page works

**What are custom controls?**

Custom controls are compiled code components that execute on the server, expose the object model, and render markup text, such as HTML or XML, as a normal Web Form or user control does.

[Overview of user controls vs. custom controls](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667)